# Placing block inside a node (positioning block between specific elements in node's content)

Tags: nodes, blocks

Basically I created a webform and enabled it as a block, now I want to put that block inside a specific node. I can do that by placing it in a 'content' region and defining the specific node BUT it displays at the end of the content. Now how can I move it between specific elements inside the content?

The node is using a page-type....tpl.php which is used by 5 other nodes as well so I cannot change the code.

To visualize it looks like:

[ content ]

-description text-

-list of videos-

[ end of content ]

and I need to put my webform between the text and the video list. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

Give the [Block reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockreference) module a try.

> Defines a field type Block reference which creates a relationship to a
>   block and allows the block to be displayed as the content of the
>   field.

Answer (score 0):

You provide only little information but here are some suggestions:

- You could put the list of videos in a custom block and place it after the webform block.
- You could put the list of videos in a view and output it in a block and place it after the webform block.
- You could use panels
- You could use Semantic Fields for your CT and output the needed fields as blocks

I guess there are more options for sure, but that comes to my mind right now.

Comment: Edit: And, to answer your question: I don't know of a way to put a webform between node fields.